# How to make this one to many query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help makeing this selection.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Those are the 2 tables.
First table:
-there are Unique/Primary buyID-s( we can say that here buyID is and Order)
-distID-s can be many.

Second table:

-This table does not have an unique indentifier 
-same buyID here ca more than one(basically buyID here offers more details on order, offers the a list of products for that order(buyID) from first table.

What I am trying to do, but I can't figure how to write the query:
-Select all buyID-s Where distID=119 From table 1(buyID-s will be 1724,1833 and 1890)
-From Table 2, sum the quantity, where buyID(from table2)=buyID(from table1).

As a result I must have:
distID=119
      buyID=1724--------quantity=25 (as an example)
      buyID=1833--------quantity=60
      buyID=1890--------quantity=23(if there will also be the product_number list, will be awesome)

I hope this make sense.
I am not too much experienced,I am trying for @ an hour, I am sure is not too hard, but this piss me of...

I am waiting for abit of help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFTJOIN` and `GROUP BY`

```
select t1.distID, t2.buyID,sum(t2.quantity) as quantity
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.buyID = t1.buyID
where t1.distID = 119
group by t1.distID, t2.buyID
```

If you also want to include *product_number* in resultset, then you have to select them using aggregate function like `MAX(product_number) as product_number` since the query use *GROUP BY* clause.

Answer (score 0):

select sum(quantity) from Table2 where buyID in (select buyID from Table1 where distID=119)